# Unwanted <p:resetInput> behaviour on JSF Form

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I'm using p:resetInput to allow users to clear specific fields when they want, but if I type something on these Text areas, and simply press enter while the focus is on a inputText, it clears the first textArea of the form.

Version:
JSF 2.2
Primefaces 5.2

Example:

```
<h:form>
    <p:inputTextarea id="test"></p:inputTextarea>
    <p:commandButton value="Clear" update="test" process="@this">
        <p:resetInput target="test"></p:resetInput>
     </p:commandButton>
     <br />

     <p:inputTextarea id="test2"></p:inputTextarea>
    <p:commandButton value="Clear" update="test2" process="@this">
        <p:resetInput target="test2"></p:resetInput>
     </p:commandButton>
     <br />

     <p:inputText id="input_id" > </p:inputText>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Perfectly correct behaviour. Pressing enter triggers the first button (according to html specs) and in your case that resets thing.

Comment: Added the type attribute to type="button" and it stopped submiting the form, thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately the button also stopped working, I'm gonna try a workaround using javascript to clear the element.

Comment: But it is just cleared client-side then... All these buttons to clear individual fields makes the ui very crowded